# reload component real time when adding an item to an array. Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a question and if this question is a multiple choice question I have an array of `questionOptions` where I can add or remove them. If I'm creating a new question then this happens in real time when I press the add or remove button, but when editing a question when the buttons are clicked nothing happens, in order to see the change I have to change the response type to something else and then change it back and then I can see the changes, this shouldn't be happening I want it to happen the same way when the question is new.

The way my project is set up is that I use a dialog box both for creating a new question and editing a question, there is a variable called `mode` which can be either `new` or `edit`.

These are the methods in the vue

```
//methods for creating or editing a question
create() {
    this.reset();
    this.mode = 'Nuevo';
    this.dialogFormVisible = true;
    this.active = '';
},
edit(model) {
    this.mode = 'Editar';
    this.form = _.cloneDeep(model);
    if (this.form.optional === 1) {
        this.form.optional = true;
    }
    if (this.form.show_text === 1) {
        this.form.show_text = true;
    }
    this.form.questionOptions = model.survey_question_option;
    this.dialogFormVisible = true;

    if (this.form.image || this.form.video) {
        this.active = '1';
    } else if (!this.form.image && !this.form.video) {
        this.active = '';
    }
},

// for adding and removing from the array
addOption() {
    this.form.questionOptions.push({
        option: ''
    });
},
removeOption(index) {
    this.form.questionOptions.splice(index, 1);
},
```

This is how the array is displayed in the dialog box

```
<div v-if="form.response_type_id === 2">
    <el-row>
        <el-col :span="20">
            <p class="el-form-item__label">Options</p>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="4">
            <div class="btn-link-plus action-button" @click="addOption()">
                <span style="font-size: small;">Add Options</span>
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </div>
        </el-col>
    </el-row>
    <el-row>
        <el-form-item label="Required answers?" prop="num">
            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-input-number controls-position="right"
                    :min="1" :max="form.questionOptions.length"
                    v-model="form.num"></el-input-number>
            </el-col>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-row>

//displaying them here
    <div v-for="(option, index) in form.questionOptions" :key="index">
        <el-row>
            <el-col :span="22">
                <el-form-item prop="option">
                    <el-input v-model="option.option"></el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
            <el-col :span="2">
                <div class="btn-link-delete action-button" @click="removeOption(index)">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </div>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything that could be making this only happen when the question is being edited? What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `model` has no parameter `questionOptions`.
Assigning `this.form = _.cloneDeep(model)` you makes your `form` reactive, but then `this.form.questionOptions = model.survey_question_option` makes parameter `questionOptions` not reactive:

You can do this way:

```js
// modify your model object
model = _.cloneDeep(model);
if (model.optional === 1) {
    model.optional = true;
}
if (model.show_text === 1) {
    model.show_text = true;
}
model.questionOptions = model.survey_question_option;
// make it reactive
this.form = model;

this.dialogFormVisible = true;

if (this.form.image || this.form.video) {
    this.active = '1';
} else if (!this.form.image && !this.form.video) {
    this.active = '';
}
```

Comment: A simpler way is to just replace `this.form.questionOptions = model.survey_question_option;` by `this.form = {...this.form, questionOptions: model.survey_question_option};`, a one line change, and a good practice whenever introducing new properties to a reactive object.

Comment: @coyotte508 where would I do the cloneDeep in that one line of code?

Comment: @Nancy my comment was an answer on its own. Just change the one line in *your* code with the one line I gave.

Comment: @coyotte508 I ended up putting this line `model.questionOptions = model.survey_question_option;` above the `model = _.cloneDeep(model);` in the original code and it works great, thanks for the suggestion!